# Reshaping long pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very simple dataframe, made of only one column and the indexes.  This is a very long column (52 rows) and I would like to group the items in groups of, let's say, 5 and put indexes and values side by side. Something like going from this

```
       value
index
1      123
2      345
...
...
...
...
...
...
52     567
```

to this

```
      value          value       .... 
index         index         ....
1     123     6      ###
2     345     7      ###
3     567     8      ###
4     678     9      ###
5     789     10     ###
```

All for visual clarity, so that then I can simply do `df.to_latex()` without having to arrange things in latex. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi jezrael! I tried it and it wasn't working as I wanted, but I was running out of time so I had to use a completely different solution for my problem and I didn't have the chance to investigate further, I'm sorry :(

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: As soon as I have time I will check it btw, so I can mark it as correct or propose some modifications

Comment: Sure, let me know if something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First create new column from index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), then create `MultiIndex` by floor divison by `5` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), change order of columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). Last convert `MultiIndex` to columns by `map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': list(range(10, 19))
})

df = df.reset_index()
       .set_index([df.index % 5, df.index // 5])
       .unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
print (df)
   index_0  value_0  index_1  value_1
0      0.0     10.0      5.0     15.0
1      1.0     11.0      6.0     16.0
2      2.0     12.0      7.0     17.0
3      3.0     13.0      8.0     18.0
4      4.0     14.0      NaN      NaN
```